# Sum a column values before a certain date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with multiple columns. The two columns I'm looking at are something like this:

```
           date                score     
 0          ..                   ..
 1          ..                   ..
 2          ..                   ..
 ..         ..                   ..
190      2019-01-14              1
191      2019-01-22              1
192      2019-02-25              0
..         ..                    ..
..         ..                    ..
200      2020-02-19              1  
..         ..                    ..
205      2020-03-15              1
..         ..                    ..
..         ..                    ..
..         ..                    ..
```

I want a line of code which sums up the values in the score column before the date 2020-02-19 (beginning of the corona period).

I don't know how to make a conditional term within a syntax to do this. I used groupby and I know it's not the correct way since there is nothing to be grouped.

I want an float variable output with one line of code using pandas not numpy to show the summation of the score column before the date I mentioned.

Comment: `x = df[ df['date'] < '2020-02-19' ]['score'].sum()`?